# Monitor Column Size Family on BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

In order to assign consumption and costs for usage in a better way, we are looking to monitor at the column size family. Is this currently available or should I raise a feature request?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to monitor the table size broken down by column family?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!Yes, that's what we require to do

Comment: It's not currently available, so feel free to raise a feature request.

Comment: OK, I thought so but wanted to see if there was any workaround or anything we could do. But I'll raise the feature request then.
Thanks for the support!